# Temporary destruction of measures in intermediate models

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, large-cardinals

It is a well-known theorem that if $\kappa$ is measurable, then there is a generic extension in which $\kappa$ is no longer weakly compact, but we can force its weak compactness back and recover the full measurability.

Is it possible to refine this result?

> **Question.** Suppose that $\kappa$ is measurable, is there a forcing $\Bbb{P*Q}$ which preserves the measurability of $\kappa$, but $\Bbb P$ only preserves its weak compactness/Ramsey/other large cardinal properties while violating measurability?

Comment: Apter and Shelah presented a  way of doing this different from the well-know Kunen method, but I don't know if it gives what you want. See [An interesting way to kill and resurrect measurability](https://mhabic.github.io/2018/12/17/an-interesting-way-to-kill-and-resurrect-measurability.html). So maybe Miha can say more on this.

Comment: I see. So if the measurable is at least indestructible under Cohen forcing (as a WC cardinal, at the very least), then the first step should "probably" preserve WC, right?

Comment: So are you asking for something like "killing them softly" and then resurrecting?

Comment: @Miha: Something like that, I suppose.

Comment: I haven't thought about this, but it seems very plausible to me that the Apter--Shelah argument (after suitable preparation) will preserve weak compactness and kill measurability in a resurrectible way. Even Ramsey might be doable. I'll see if I can sit down and work out the details.

Comment: @Miha: I had a chat with David Asperó about this and he suggested the Kunen-Paris theorem where we add a Cohen subset to every regular cardinal below the measurable (Theorem 17.10 in Kanamori) as a possible option.

Comment: I don't see how that would preserve weak compactness. The reflection you get from a weakly compact is good enough to detect that you added Cohen sets everywhere below $\kappa$, but not at $\kappa$, so you would lose weak compactness.

Comment: The point of the Apter--Shelah argument is that you kill measurability using an object that really has size $\kappa^+$, which should let more "local" large cardinal properties, like weak compactness or Ramseyness, survive.

Comment: @Miha: Ask Kunen and Paris, since that is how you turn a measurable into a weakly compact that has a $\kappa^+$ saturated ideal, but not a $\kappa$ saturated one.

Comment: for weak compactness, how about adding a weakly compact set that has no weakly compact initial segment, followed by shooting a 1-club through its complement (with suitable preparation from below)?

Comment: @Otto: Ah, that's an interesting idea.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What about the following idea: start with supercompact $\kappa$ and force with reverse Easton iteration to add $\alpha^{++}$-many Cohen subsets to each inaccessible $\alpha \leq \kappa.$ $\kappa$ remains supercompact in the extension. For intermediate submodel consider the iteration below $\kappa$ the same, but at $\kappa$ just add one $\kappa$-Cohen set!

Comment: @Mohammad: That is also a very nice idea. I can imagine Menachem suggesting this solution over a coffee. :-)

Comment: Yes, indeed this idea should work, as when I want to prove weak compactness is preserved, I take a nice model $M$ of size $\kappa$ and from outside, $\kappa^{++}$ of $M$ has size $\kappa$, noting adding one cohen subset to $\kappa$ is the same as adding $\kappa$-many.

Comment: But the point here is that I work with something stronger than measurability at the beginning (though I preserve it).

Comment: I understand the Kunen--Paris suggestion better now, and it should indeed work. By adding a Cohen subset to each $\gamma<\kappa$, but not at $\kappa$, you kill the measurability of $\kappa$, but weak compactness survives since you can just _build_ the stage $\kappa$ generic you need for the size $\kappa$ model. Measurability gets resurrected once you add a the last Cohen subset (this is very much like Mohammad's idea, but doesn't need a supercompact, although it also doesn't affect the GCH pattern). I actually now suspect that these forcings will also preserve Ramsey properties of $\kappa$...